# L and R poles are flipped using Rigify

Tags: rigify

When I generated the rig I noticed that the L and R poles (set to the proper feet by default) are flipped. This obviously causes quite a few issues. I used the metarig in 2.91 and only removed the facial controls.

[image: Poles on knees are flipped.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your metarig's legs are set up correctly.
The only bend allowed in an IK chain is the one to indicate in which way it should bend. If you do it wrong, Blender will orient your IK wrong.

Also check your bones' orient.

As you can see below, I just shifted the metarig knees on the side and it generated the same way as yours.

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you. I'll double check them. The process that I did was from a tutorial that mentioned to do a recalculate roll on the character which is where I now believe where the issue came from.

Comment: After doing some experimenting it appears that was exactly the issue. Even though it appeared that the bone axis were correct; adjusting the bone roll (shift + N) seemed to mess with the knees. Thanks for your help on this.